# Convert Borland CHR Font Format

Tags: file-conversion

Is there any way to convert a file in Borland's CHR font format to any other format? Or does anyone know how I can programmatically parse this format in order to create an output myself (I'm a programmer)? Having an output as SVG would totally fine.

To be clear: I need an automatable way not manual conversion as I have a whole bunch of CHR files to convert.

Comment: I have no CHR files to test, but this site lists it as an input option: http://www.fontconverter.org/

Comment: @Mysterfxit: Yes, I've seen this, but it failed on the files I have :-( My files are working ones from Borland engraving machines.

Comment: Did you see the file format specification? http://www.fileformat.info/format/borland-chr/corion.htm

Comment: @Mysterfxit: Yes, but I've never parsed any binary files ...

Comment: Then you might get more help in http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ or one of the programming SEs.  You can reference this URL that has a link to the spec and sample CHR files.  Good luck. http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/CHR_(Borland_font)

Comment: Like @jor, I have also tried fontconverter.org but it doesn't work on Borland fonts. I think it supports a different CHR format.

Comment: @Kirkman14: As it turned out my files where additionally encrypted. I used some test files from here (http://cd.textfiles.com/aztechsg/QUIKMENU/) and could easily verify the format (http://www.fileformat.info/format/borland-chr/corion.htm). Actually gave up on the encryption then. By the way, this library contains a CHR parser: http://grx.gnu.de/index.html (download source and look into grx249s/src/fonts/fdv_bgi.h and .c).

Comment: @jor: I have been experimenting with rendering the Borland CHR fonts in HTML5. Wrote my own (probably ugly) parser. http://localhost/~kirkman/ripscrip.js/borland/chr-parser-coords.php